# What are the invariants of this field's equation of motion?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-fields, invariance

### Background

Let's say I have a field/fluid which occupies a volume element $dV$ then equation of motion is given by:

$$
\left( \frac{1}{c} \frac{\partial V}{\partial t} \right)^2
 = \phi_{xy}^2 + \phi_{yz}^2 + \phi_{zx}^2
$$

where $t$ is time, $c$ is a constant, $\phi_{xy}$ is the flux through the $xy$ plane of of the surface, $\phi_{yz}$ is the flux through the $yz$ plane of the surface and $\phi_{zx}$ is the flux through the surface of the $zx$ plane.

### Question

What are the invariants of this field? For example is it radially symmetric? Is there some nice way to visualize  it's time evolution?